# Ajax code runs correctly on firefox but not on chrome

Tags: ajax

link to project files: http://full-stack.fr/uploads/6/
Any suggetions ?
thanks in advance

Comment: Use console.log to check the div here like:
`console.log(document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0]);`

I'm guessing this doesn't print the div that you want

Comment: actually it does print the div. think there s a problen with the div.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;

Comment: That's what I'm trying to tell you. The printed div isn't the one that you need. Try disabling all chrome extensions and try again. Since they might be adding some extra divs to the DOM.

Comment: ah i see thanks for your answer. i will try this as soon as i get home

Comment: I'll add this as the answer with a better explanation

Comment: You should really post a [Minimal, verifiable, and complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try disabling all chrome extensions and try again. Since they might be adding some extra divs to the DOM, thereby interfering with the 
`document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0]` statement.

Comment: Actually that works thank you, now am wondering how to get my program runs without having to disable axtensions...

Comment: @MOHAMEDHOUSNI what you ought to do is use ids to get element using [getElementById](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementbyid.asp) instead of using `getElementsByTagName` that can match multiple divs

Comment: perfect thznk you !